# Google Chrome "user agent stylesheet"

Tags: html, css

I've set up reset.css already.

```
html,body,div,ul,ol,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
```

but the browser still use the default stylesheet。

[image]

Because the code is too long to upload.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: The `user agent stylesheet` is the default style the browser uses for the document, but you can always override it with your own style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to be imagining that a rule overrides/replaces/shadows **all** properties for its selector(s). That, of course, is not the case. A rule such as

```
html,body,div,ul,ol,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4{
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
}
```

specifies **only** the `margin` and `padding` properties for the specified selectors. Other properties for those selectors, including `display` etc., will continue to be drawn from wherever they might have been specified, including the user agent default stylesheet.

Note that `-webkit-margin-*` properties are the way Chrome sets up its defaults to be more general in the case of right-to-left layouts. However, they are separate from the `margin` properties, and hence will not be shown as being overridden (struck-out) because a higher-priority rule specifies a `margin`. However, when Chrome goes to calculate the margin, it will give precedence to the `margin` property over the `-webkit-margin-*` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Every browser uses its default stylesheet before applying the user created one. As your screenshot suggests, you overwrite the margin and the padding. All additional styling the browser needs to display the content are taken from the browser specific stylesheet (for example the font family, font size, color,...).

As some browsers render some elements different than others, there are projects as https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ to "normalize" the rendering.

Comment: Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
html,body,div,ul,ol,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 -webKit-margin-start: 0;
 -webKit-padding-start: 0;
```

}

Comment: Sorry, wrote it from my iPhone.

Comment: Thank you for your help,

Comment: There is no such property as `-webkit-margin`.

Answer (score -1):

This is normal every browser use default properties
[Chrome Default CSS](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/blink/+/master/Source/core/css/html.css)

Comment: Thank you for your help,